# How to use the List<Account> value created in ApexClass in Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, list

My Apex Class is like this.

```java
public with sharing class displayWarning {
    ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public displayWarning (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public List<Account> showAcc() {
        User m = (User)controller.getRecord();
        List<Account> relatedAccounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 5];
        return relatedAccounts ;
    }

    public PageReference markread() {
        User m = (User)controller.getRecord();
        m.MessageShown__c = false;
        update m;
        return null;
    }
}
```

My Visualforce Page is like this.

```html
<apex:page standardController="User" extensions="displayWarning">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!markread}" name="myFunction" oncomplete="alert(1);"/>
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!showAcc}" name="myFunction1" oncomplete="alert(2);"/>

        <script>
        if({!User.MessageShown__c} && {!User.UserTrigger__c == 1})
        {
            var accounts = myFunction1();
            var tableHtml = '<table border="1"><tr><th>Account Id</th></tr>';
            for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
                tableHtml += '<tr><td>' + accounts[i].Id + '</td></tr>';
            }
            tableHtml += '</table>';
            alert('There are Account records owned by the user who wants to be inactivated:\n\n' + tableHtml);   
   
            setTimeout(function(){ myFunction(); }, 2000);
        }
        </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My Apex Trigger is like this.

```java
trigger UserTrigger on User (before update) {
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (User updatedUser : Trigger.new) {
        if (updatedUser.IsActive != Trigger.oldMap.get(updatedUser.Id).IsActive) {
            if (!updatedUser.IsActive) {
                List<Account> relatedAccounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = :updatedUser.Id AND RC_Active__c = true LIMIT 1];
                if (!relatedAccounts.isEmpty()) {
                      updatedUser.UserTrigger__c = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display the list returned from the `showAcc` function as a table in the alert, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Visualforce is generally not "reactive". The `{!User.MessageShown__c} && {!User.UserTrigger__c == 1}` is only evaluated once, server-side, before the page is rendered in your browser.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand you fully, what is your suggestion?

Comment: Your code won't work for a number of reasons, actually, not just what Derek suggested. However, without more context, we can't exactly give you a straight answer, either. What is the goal of your code? What is the expected user experience? Pretend like we're new on the job, don't know anything about your Salesforce org or business, and you're trying to give us a user story. Be as descriptive as you can be.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox,
 the scenario I designed is as follows When a user is inactivated on the User profile, my trigger named UserTrigger, which I shared above, checks whether this user has any active Accounts.
If there is, this UserTrigger assigns a value of 1 to my__c field.

Comment: Then, if the Visualforce Page value MessageShown__c and UserTrigger__c == 1 value I use in the User Profile layout is true, it should give a warning in the alert and present 5 customers belonging to the relevant user in the table, where the MessageShown__c field is a checkbox that comes true by default in all users. I use the MessageShown__c field to redirect the message only once.
In Apex Class, you can see the related running functions.